# Enter a Number between 10 and 30 with do-while

Tags: javascript

Question I want to know this:
If I enter a number through DO-While between 10 and 30
I want the number to be from 10 to 30 and if it is less or more, repeat the message
Enter a Number between 10 and 30 with do-while
I have set these conditions but it validates me when it is less than 10 but if it is greater than 30, some idea does not validate me because both are not validated.
Thank you

```js
let num
    do {
        num=Number(prompt("Enter a Number between 10 and 30"))
        if((num<10) && (num<30)){
            alert(`The number ${num} must be Entree 10 and 30`)
        }
    } while ((num<10) && (num<30));
    alert(`The number is ${num} and is in the range of 10 and 30`)
```

Comment: Theres a mistake inside the condition behind the while brackets should be while (num <10 || num > 30)

Comment: you are asking for a number "lower than 10 and lower than 30", but you want "lower than 10 or higher than 30"

Comment: Thank you very much friend But it explains to me why I don't work with && and if with ||, I have that doubt

Comment: && simply means that you are asking for both conditions to be true in order to get inside the if statement.  num < 10 && num <30 is translated to num has to be smaller than 10 AND smaller than 30. Changing it to || means num has to be smaller than 10 OR smaller than 30

Answer (score 0):

You should change the if condition as

```
if((num<10) || (num>30))
```

If you use `&&` then it will  validate if both the conditions are true.

Comment: Thank you very much friend But it explains to me why I don't work with && and if with ||, I have that doubt

Comment: x && y means if x and y both are true. x || y means if x or y is true (If x true and y false or y true and x false the if condition will pass )